# how to work large tables in mvc5 asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I am building a website using asp .net mvc 5 infrastructure,the table which the model is connected to is very large 1500+ entries so when the client loads the page,he gets the entire table in one HTML page.

My question is how can i divide the table into several pages?
I am using DataTables but open to other suggestions.

Comment: implementing paging will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the asp.net documentation about pagination? Here is a link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

You should take a look at: PagedList.Mvc NuGet package and see if that is a solution for you.